# Retry API call when value is not there

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, httpclient

Is there a way to continuously poll my API until a value is retrieved (but stop when it fails)? Right now, it makes the call, but as there is nothing there at the time, it does not retry. I want the retries to continue unless the call fails.

**Component**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.getCurrentUser(this.uid);
  }

  getCurrentUser(uid: string) {
    this.userService.getUser(uid).then((user: IUser[]) => {
      if (user && user.length > 0) {
        this.user = user[0];
      }
    });
  }
```

**Service**

```
  getUser(uid: string): Promise<Object | IUser[]> {
    return this.firebaseService.generateToken().then((token: string) => {
      return this.httpClient
        .get(`${environment.apiBasePath}/users/${uid}`, {
          headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        })
        .toPromise();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Could put a loop on your service function although this seems like a strange thing to do. Curious what the case is that requires this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the function again from within itself if there is no data being returned.

```
getCurrentUser(uid: string) {
    this.userService.getUser(uid)
      .then((user: IUser[]) => {
        if (user && user.length > 0) {
          this.user = user[0];
        } else {
          this.getCurrentUser(this.uid)
        }
      })
      .catch(error = console.error(error);
  }
```

Perhaps set a limit on how many times you want this to happen?  Or set use a `setTimeout` on the recall (in the else clause) so that it doesn't happen too rapidly?